# Count in a Procedure

Tags: sql-server

There's two tables with a 1:M relationship between,
(Citizen table) and (card table)
Now every Card includes many Citizen...

What I need to do is to count the number of users of every card, and put the result in a column in Card table
That's the function:

```
Select Count (Citizen.ID)From [Citizen] Inner Join [Card] On Card.ID = Citizen.Card_ID;
```

I tried to add that function to a procedure, but I don't how to set it

```
Create proc CountUsers
(
@Number_of_users
)


Declare @Number_of_users nvarchar(10)
Set 
Select Count (Citizen.ID)From Citizen Inner Join Card
On Citizen.Card_ID = Card.ID;
```

Comment: you can group it by userid and and use update

Comment: can you please share your input and expected output

Comment: I would suggest that you don't want to store the count here. Unless there are millions of rows in this table storing the count like this is not necessary. You should just calculate that as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Select 
     Card.ID, Count(*) 
From [Citizen] 
Inner Join [Card] 
    On Card.ID = Citizen.Card_ID 
group by Card.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `scalar valued function` rather than a `stored procedure` and use that in your scripts that `insert` into your `Card` table:

```
create function CountCitizensByCardID
(
@CardID int
)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @Return int;

    select @Return = count(Citizen.ID)
    from Citizen
        inner join Card
            on Card.ID = Citizen.Card_ID
    where Citizen.Card_ID = @CardID;

    return @Return;
end
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
select ID
      ...
      ,CountCitizensByCardID(ID) as CitizenCount
from Card;
```

Comment: More explaining, please :)

Comment: @Hady.J.Wolf  More explaining about which part?  Have you tried googling the bits you don't understand?